# Asymptote when $x\to-\infty$

Tags: calculus

I have function $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2+5x}$ and need asymptote when $x\to-\infty$. I know that

$$\;\sqrt{4x^2+5x}=\sqrt{x^2\left(4+\frac5x\right)}=|x|\sqrt{4+\frac5x}=-x\sqrt{4+\frac5x}$$

since I assume $\;x<0\implies |x|=-x\;$ . I also have

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5x}}x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-x\sqrt{4+\frac5x}}x=-2$$

And now problem: I already drew sketch of function after I found asymptote when $\;x\to\infty\;$, and I get no asymptote when $\;x\to-\infty$,but:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2+5x}-(-2x)\right)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2+5x}+2x\right)\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+5x}-2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+5x}-2x)}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{5x}{\sqrt{4x^2+5x}-2x)}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{5x}{-x\sqrt{4+\frac5x}-2x}=-\frac54$$

and I get asymptote $y=-2x-\frac54$...!

What is my mistake, please?

Comment: Note:  $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{-2x-\frac54}{x}=-2$

Comment: This function has the oblique asymptotes $$y=\pm\left(2x+\frac54\right)$$

Comment: Your asymptote is perfectly correct – but it's shorter and simpler to obtain with the binomial expanson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, the asymptote you computed is correct.  Perhaps you did not see an asymptote when $x\to-\infty$ in your sketch because you sketched wrong, so here is a picture of the function's graph:

[image: picture of the function]

And as [Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard) commented, it is easier to obtain the asymptote using the binomial expansion:

as ${x\to-\infty}, \sqrt{4x^2+5x}= -2x\sqrt{1+\dfrac5{4x}}=-2x\left(1+\dfrac5{8x}+o\left(\dfrac1x\right)\right)\to-2x-\dfrac5{4}.$

Comment: I think it's better to add a complementary term in the form $o\bigl(\frac1x\bigr)$ – too many students believe this kind of computation lacks rigour.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Bernard; I have edited to accommodate it [replaced ... with $o\left(\dfrac1x\right)$]

Comment: Thanks you very much.